# Use ChromiumFX/ChromiumWebBrowser inside an C# addin

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded

I’m trying to add a `ChromiumWebBrowser` components inside a C#/WPF addin. (Before the addin used CefSharp but the new version of the host application run addin inside custom `AppDomain` so `CefSharp` doesn’t work anymore.)

To the problem is, when I call `ChromiumWebBrowser.Initialize()` a new instance of the host application is launch  (with some command line args which are dropped by the application).

I really don’t understand the stuff around this command line.

Can you explain to me where I do a mistake ? `ChromiumWebBrowser` cannot be used inside addin ? I miss somethings ?

Here the `C#` sample of my code

```
public partial class myWindow : Window
{
        public myWindow()
        {

            CfxRuntime.LibCefDirPath = @"E:\sources\app\Output\Debug_msvc2017_x64\Addins\cef\Release64";

            ChromiumWebBrowser.OnBeforeCfxInitialize += ChromiumWebBrowser_OnBeforeCfxInitialize;
            ChromiumWebBrowser.OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing += ChromiumWebBrowser_OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing;
            Chromium.WebBrowser.ChromiumWebBrowser.Initialize();

            InitializeComponent();

            // browser is a ChromiumWebBrowser instance
            browser.MouseClick += Wb_MouseClick;
            browser.Show();
        }


        private void Wb_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as ChromiumWebBrowser).LoadUrl("https://www.google.com"); // properly trigger but nothings will be displayed
        }

        static void ChromiumWebBrowser_OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing(CfxOnBeforeCommandLineProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.CommandLine.CommandLineString); // here the command line create a new instance of the application where the plugin is loaded
        }

        static void ChromiumWebBrowser_OnBeforeCfxInitialize(OnBeforeCfxInitializeEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Settings.LocalesDirPath = @"E:\sources\app\Output\Debug_msvc2017_x64\Addins\cef\locales";
            e.Settings.ResourcesDirPath = @"E:\sources\app\Output\Debug_msvc2017_x64\Addins\cef\Resources";
        }    
}
```

‌
And the `xaml` part
‌

```
<Window x:Class="App.Views.myWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views"
        xmlns:webbrowser="clr-namespace:Chromium.WebBrowser;assembly=ChromiumWebBrowser"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="myWindow" Height="800" Width="1200">
    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="wpfContainer">
            <webbrowser:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser"></webbrowser:ChromiumWebBrowser>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

‌

Thanks in advance for your help ;)